# C++ Template Function string type not matching?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function defined:

```
template<class T> 
inline void _assert(const string& message, T expected, T actual);
```

I have been using it to assert 2 integers are equals. But when I had:

```
_assert("Modifies(15, v) for v value", "h", varTable->getVarName(list.at(0)));
                                            ^ returns std::string
```

It doesn't work:

```
Error   1   error C2782: 'void _assert(const std::string &,T,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous  h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\test\testqueryevaluator\testgetcandidatelist.cpp 183
```

Why? 2 strings are not of the same type?

Comment: Because one argument is a `const char *`, and the other a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `getVarName()` returns an `std::string`, but the second argument you supply to `_assert()` is of type `const char[]` (decays to `const char*`).

The two types are not identical, and therefore type deduction cannot find a valid match for `T`.

To fix it, you could wrap your string literal `"h"` into an `std::string` object:

```
_assert(
    "Modifies(15, v) for v value", 
    string("h"), // <== Wrap the string literal
    varTable->getVarName(list.at(0))
    );
```

Or you could just modify your `_assert()` function template so that it does not force the expected and actual value to be of the same type:

```
template<typename T, typename Y> 
inline void _assert(const string& message, T expected, U actual);
```

Beware though: if you are using equality comparison (`operator ==`) inside `_assert` to compare the expected and the actual value, make sure your `T` and `U` are not deduced to be `const char*` if you want to compare strings; otherwise, your comparison will not do what you expect.

Comment: `std::string string("h"); assert("h" == string.c_str());` fails (pointer comparison). So discard the first example and use `std::string` comparison instead.

Comment: @Zeta: Correct. Haven't considered that `_assert` would do a comparison by equality. Let me edit

Comment: Actually, I guess you could spice up the last version by using `static_assert(std::is_convertible<T,U>::value, "Cannot convert T to U in _assert"); _assert(message,expected,T(actual));` or something similar.

Comment: @Zeta: `T` and `U` are deduced inside `_assert` though, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `"h"` is of type `const char*` and your second parameter is of type `std::string` so it cannot figure out which you want.

You should make them the same type:

```
_assert("Modifies(15, v) for v value", std::string("h"), varTable->getVarName(list.at(0)));
```

or change your function to take two different params:

```
template<class T, class U> 
inline void _assert(const string& message, T expected, U actual);
```